# цикл 1,2,3 в java

Tags: java

Как сделать цикл `1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...`

Comment: `while (true) {i=(i%3)+1;...}`

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос понятнее.

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует описывать вопрос более развернуто, но постараюсь угадать, кажется вам нужно это:

```
    int i=1;
    while(true){
        System.out.println(""+i++);
        if(i>3)i=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант :-)

```
public class Cycle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        while (true) {
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```
Stream.generate(() -> Stream.of(1,2,3))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .limit(9) //если убрать limit, то будет бесконечный стрим
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Классное решение. я пытался что то похожее через стримы сделать, но ваш вариант намного элегантнее

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
 IntStream
          .generate(new IntSupplier() {
                private int index = 0;

                @Override
                public int getAsInt() {
                    return (index++) % 3 + 1;
                }})
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

+ 1 вариант:

```
    public class Cicle {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
            while (true) {
                for (Integer integer : a) {
                    System.out.print(integer + ",");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```